What is the intended/best-practice PYTHONPATH workflow for developing a python module with a venv?
I'm a relative python newbie and find myself going back and forth on  how to set the sys.path "nicely" while developing my module with a venv, and thought I'd ask if/what the best-practice way is to make
python3 -m my_module.src1 args

use the files I'm developing in src/**?
My module uses hatchling in a pyproject.toml file file and I set it up with this structure:
/path/to/work/dir
    pyproject.toml
    venv/
    src/
        my_module/
            __init__.py
            src1.py
            src2.py

I create the venv with
python3 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate

# Install all dependencies for my_module
pip3 install .

What works is to:
source $PWD/venv/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD/src

in every shell, perhaps with direnv.
Is that what is intended?
I've read so many pages about this recently, so please excuse the lack of references:

I've seen recommendations to to modify ./venv/bin/activate to set PYTHONPATH and recommendations to definitely don't do that.
I've seen recommendations to create a ./venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/some.pth file with a full path to my ./src and that works as long as my_module is not installed in the venv, because that path is appended to sys.path. But my_module is installed in venv since I used pip3 install . to install all my dependencies (and to test installation). So using a .pth file is useless because regardless, it will find and use the installed my_module.

I was just wondering if there was some best-practice way to do this.

python setup.py develop -- to be used instead of pip install . -- is meant for exactly this case. (BTW -- on [meta.se], see Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing? discussing rationale for a general presumption that best-practice questions are likely to be considered opinion-based).

That said, personally, I live in the Nix world, which has a completely different set of solutions for this problem -- not just bundling custom Python modules but a completely arbitrary software stack, compiling and installing software/libraries/&c written in completely different languages and putting those in PATH in addition to setting up your PYTHONPATH; this means that if, say, you need a libc patch to fix a bug in a C extension to a Python module, you can have Nix build a libc with that patch, and link a Python interpreter against it).

(I can think of exactly one time in my career I had to patch glibc for that class of reason, but... well, once is more than never; such things do happen -- whereas needing a different openssl is much more common, and another example of a place where the Python virtualenv approach is simply inadequate to task).
